# VirtualBox - Windows XP machine "A network cable is unplugged"

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10, virtualbox-networking

Out of nowhere my virtual machine's internet stopped working. I changed nothing in the settings to cause this but, after it stopped working, I changed somethings.

The Virtual Machine:

[image: The XP VM]

The settings:

[image: VB Settings]

I am using:

```
Virtualbox version:5.0.4_Ubuntu r102546
```

On:

```
xubuntu 15.10
```

Comment: Your VM shows two network adapters, but your settings only show the settings for one of them. Can you provide the settings for the other one as well.  It might be as easy as just ticking the box that says `Cable Connected`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/0vbcqfh

Comment: The new image you posted is also for adapter 1. Could you post the one for adapter 2 - as I asked originally.

Comment: adapter 2 is disabled i got it working for a day by installing PRO2K3XP_32 (intell drivers) but i stopped working again with no reasons....

Answer (score 0):

A couple days ago, my VB with XP stopped resizing the screen when resizing the window, so I reinstalled the Guest Additions. Didn't work for me, but you could try doing this.

Finally I ended up upgrading the VB to the latest version (v5) and everything works again. No need to reconfigure anything on the guest OS. Just open the virtual machine with the new version.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits
and now, VirtualBox 5.0.10 r104061

Hope it helps.